# Product use documentation and company customer service info conflict, which info is the company liable for?

Tags: canada, liability

In Canada (Ontario) a customer buys a product manufactured by company A.

One of the components of the product is produced by a third party (company B) and has a label stating the limitations of this component.

Companies A customer service representative informs the customer that this product and all its components can be used in a manner that conflicts with the label.

If the use of the product in the manner suggested by customer service causes damage, is Company A responsible for this or should the labels on the product always be followed regardless of information acquired externally.

Concrete example:
Product has a power supply adapter that has a label stating that it can only be used inside. No information in the manuals say that this product can be used outside. A customer service representative says that the product is made and can be used outside.

If because this product was used outside it causes damages, is the company responsible?